# c# Keep file open but overwrite contents

Tags: c#, file, overwrite

I have a 3rd party application that periodically reads output from my C#.Net application.
Due to certain constraints, I can only write output to a file which then gets read by the 3rd party application.

I need to overwrite the contents of the same file each time.
I am currently doing it in C# by using

```
Loop
{
  //do some work
  File.WriteAllText(path,Text);
}
```

The 3rd party application periodically checks the file and reads the contents. This works well but pushes the CPU usage very high. Replacing File.WriteAllText with a text writer solves the issue of high CPU usage but then my text gets appended to the file instead of overwriting the file.

Could someone point me in the right direction where I can keep a file open in C# and periodically overwrite its contents without too much overhead?

Edit: I fixed the CPU usage by opting to write to the file once every 20 iterations of the loop instead of every iteration of the loop. All the answers given below work but have overhead associated with closing the file and reopening. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `File.Open` with `FileMode` `Truncate` to create the file stream for your `TextWriter`.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone point me in the right direction where I can keep a file open in C# and periodically overwrite its contents without too much overhead?

Here is how I did it in Silverlight 4.  Since you are not using Silverlight, you won't use isolated storage, but same technique will work regardless of the backing store.

The interesting bit is in the Write() method:

```
logWriter.BaseStream.SetLength(0);
```

From [`Stream.SetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c2w1ac6%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) Method:

> When overridden in a derived class, sets the length of the current stream.

Be sure to flush the stream using either AutoFlush (as I did in this example), or by adding a `logWriter.Flush()` after the `logWriter.Write()`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a log file in isolated storage.
/// </summary>
public static class Log
{
    private const string FileName = "TestLog.xml";
    private static IsolatedStorageFile isoStore;
    private static IsolatedStorageFileStream logWriterFileStream;
    private static StreamWriter logWriter;

    public static XDocument Xml { get; private set; }

    static Log()
    {
        isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        logWriterFileStream = isoStore.OpenFile(
            FileName, 
            FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write, 
            FileShare.None);
        logWriter = new StreamWriter(logWriterFileStream);
        logWriter.AutoFlush = true;

        Xml = new XDocument(new XElement("Tests"));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes a snapshot of the test log XML to isolated storage.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Write(XElement testContextElement)
    {
        Xml.Root.Add(testContextElement);
        logWriter.BaseStream.SetLength(0);
        logWriter.Write(Xml.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the text writer, but clear the contents of the file before you begin writing.  Something like this:

```
        string path = null;//path of file
        byte[] bytes_to_write = null;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);
        System.IO.FileStream str = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.Read);
        str.Write(bytes_to_write, 0, bytes_to_write.Length);
```

Perhaps something from this example will help?

Comment: Clearing the file each time in my loop using

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, string.Empty);

will also lead to the same overhead since I will have to do it repeatedly in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `false` as the `append parameter` of the constructor:

```
TextWriter tsw = new StreamWriter(path, false);
```

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Thread.Sleep?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx